# Glitchy Linux terminal behaviour - as if display buffering is broken somehow - how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, terminal, rendering

This is a quirk that I've only seen on my Dell laptop. I'm running Arch Linux, with Xorg, NVIDIA drivers, and i3 window manager. I'm not using a compositor.

It's difficult to describe but essentially when I'm working in a terminal window (doesn't seem to matter which one - `rxvt-unicode`, `xterm`), the cursor sometimes jumps back a character or two, as I'm typing. One or two of the characters I've already typed disappear, and then almost immediately reappear as the cursor jumps back to its correct location. It's as if a previous screen buffer is rendered out-of-order, momentarily showing a point in time just prior. The character input is correct, but visually it does not look right.

I've also noticed it in terminal programs like `htop`, a similar thing will happen when using the up/down arrow keys to move the highlight bar up/down. Most of the time it will move in the expected manner, but frequently it will suddenly jump to a previous position (a few rows away), then back to the correct row, as a flicker. It's visually annoying but the input is correct and it doesn't prevent me from using the application. It's not caused by reordering of the items in `htop` - I've set it to sort-by-PID and the order isn't changing.

I've checked the keyboard, and it's providing correct and accurate input. From what I can tell it's only a rendering issue - the character data into and out of the terminal is correct.

Scrolling in `nano` looks super glitchy - simply scrolling down line-by-line has the visual effect of it jumping back to a previous line every few lines.

I don't see this problem with graphical applications like Firefox. Scrolling looks perfectly fine.

How would I go about troubleshooting this unusual issue? Is this a "tearing" effect? Possible driver issue?